# Users asking ubuntu questions should be informed about askubuntu ?

Tags: feature-request

When someone asks a question with ubuntu tag they should be redirected to a page informing them about askubuntu and how asking it on that will expose the question to the more ubuntu experts.

Then give them a choice of posting it on Super User itself or posting it to Ask Ubuntu instead. This will help since most people coming here first time don't know about Ask Ubuntu .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not much of choice when you don't know you have an option and someone suggest "Post this on Ask Ubuntu instead", is it (and this is what I've seen many times in regards to Ask Different, the Apple site)? You do what that friendly person — or web site feature — tells you to do, since you didn't even know you could. You don't realize that it's merely advertisement for another site.

Many issues users with Ubuntu face aren't actually specific to that distribution. Posting these questions here might actually increase their visibility and usefulness for other users.

Ask Ubuntu isn't in beta anymore, which means it's strong enough to grow on its own by attracting new users properly instead of blatantly stealing them from other sites on the network, and doesn't need special considerations by what can be considered the "parent site".

The same applies for suggestions that Mac/Mac OS X related questions, which are on-topic on this site, "should" be migrated to Ask Different. Not necessary. Not going to happen.

This would, in the very long run, just hurt SuperUser.

Comment: I agree with the sentiments here. Our policy has been, and will be, that as long as the question is on-topic for Super User, we will not migrate questions to other Stack Exchange sites, unless _the person asking_ specifically requests it. If a question isn't getting any attention, you can comment telling them about other related sites and how to flag for a moderator to move their question, but a redirect page would not be appropriate, and would make the user experience more difficult.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. If you're asking a question that is perfectly on-topic and you're told to go elsewhere, I'd find that rather annoying (just like people saying "This belongs to *XYZ*!").

Comment: you are not told to go elsewhere you are just being made aware that there is specific site for that purpose specifically and then it is your decision .

Comment: @Alaukik Yes, I know that the decision is up to the person who asks, but still I'd consider it advertising that isn't necessary. The Ubuntu sites run well enough without having questions migrated there from SU every hour.

Comment: @nhinkle ...and the site doesn't need boosting. See my question in Ask a Moderator yesterday or the day before.

Comment: Exactly. On a similar note, @Alaukik, do you want Ask Ubuntu to have a big redirect page that says, "WAIT! You could ask your question on Super User instead, or on Unix and Linux!!"? I doubt it.

Comment: You are against making a comment (i.e. suggestion) on perhaps a better location for a question?  Afterall, most users do not have the authority to move it anyway so the user could simply ignore the comment.