# Where do questions about OS X's Automator belong?

Tags: support, scope, osx

Where do questions about scripts/programs written in [Automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_%28software%29) belong? They could belong

- on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), as they're a sort of programming.
- on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), as they are often used to automate lengthy/annoying tasks by power users.
- even on the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) Apple site, as Automator is an OS X native program.

Or could they even go on any of the three? Or others? Could it be `flagged as of topic` or `migrated` if on one of the 'wrong' sites, or is it open enough that it would be fine on any?

#### **EDIT**

According to [this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to) post, it seems that OS X questions are okay on either SP or Ask Differently, so I think that the last two options aren't really any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely fine for Super User. Just make sure to tag it [automator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/automator).

Questions about Automator are on topic for Stack Overflow and Ask Different as well. Just ask on the site you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was just curious.