# When should questions be moved to AskDifferent/AskUbuntu/...?

Tags: discussion, questions

I read [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2726/users-asking-ubuntu-questions-should-be-informed-about-askubuntu), which helped, but where is the line?

Just because a question is about an Apple product, doesn't mean it is off-topic (not at all actually) just because another (more specific) site exists for that kind of question.
Then again, a question that would be *more at home* on another SE site is bound to be duplicated on that site at some point and duplication sucks.

I feels like, generally, the opinion seems to be to keep the question on SU.
But when should it be marked off-topic then? There has to be a certain point where it is no longer SU material, but AskUbuntu material.

Comment: [Do we want to have an option to migrate to AskUbuntu?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/1572)

Comment: [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to)

Comment: [Related post of mine on Apple.SE](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/859/when-should-i-ask-here-and-when-should-i-ask-at-super-user/978#978).

Comment: Note that **Apple.SE is not more specific than Super User** in regards to Mac / Mac OS X questions. Where Super User has e.g. Linux and Windows as other topics, Apple.SE has e.g. Apple TV, iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TL;DR version

The **only** reason *someone other than the OP** should suggest or request a migration to another site is: **The question is off topic here, on topic there, and not crap** (we don't migrate crap).

If there are multiple sites that could accept a question, the OP chooses his site and community.

<sup>*The OP is always free to request migration, e.g. when there are no answers for a while and he expects more success on another site.</sup>

Comment: When you see a question that's been ignored for weeks you could suggest that there are other places to ask and explain to the OP how migration works. But that's an advanced topic and easy to get wrong (e.g. when the question is bad, or not actually on topic on the suggested destination site).

Answer (score 6):

Preferably people don't ask questions on Super User that are not allowed, such as questions about iPads or iPhones. So there normally shouldn't be any reason to migrate a question, unless it lingers here and the user feels strongly about trying to get it more attention on one of the other sites.

The idea is that you ask your question on the site where you feel at home.

Are you an Apple-aficionado and own every Apple product ever made? ask on Ask Different

Are you a Ubuntu-only user and hate Micro$oft? Ask on Ask Ubuntu

Are you an all-round computer geek and don't mind Windows questions? Ask it on Super User

So there doesn't have to be a line, because questions are expected to end up on the right side. Migrations therefore should be looked at case-by-case rather than following some strict rule

Comment: Why does using ubuntu imply hating Microsoft?

Comment: @JorgeCastro It doesn't, I was just abusing stereotypes to make a point

Answer (score 5):

To extend on Ivo's answer …

> But when should it be marked off-topic then?

By you? Probably never. By the OP? If they want it migrated, e.g. because they didn't get too much attention or later thought it was a better fit for another site, then it should be this way. They can `flag` a question for attention to have it migrated.

**If a question is on-topic here, you shouldn't flag it as off-topic.**

You can leave a constructive comment telling them that we also have another site, but don't nag about migrating it there. Inform them that they can migrate it themselves if they want to.