# How to decide whether to post on OS X related question on SU or on Apple.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration, apple, osx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should questions be moved to AskDifferent/AskUbuntu/…?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4394/when-should-questions-be-moved-to-askdifferent-askubuntu)

On one hand, my question is only applicable on an Apple device. On the other hand, many such questions seem to be posted on SU and they seem to be getting much more exposure here (and hence have a better chance of getting answered?)

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a little more detail on what the question is asking?

Comment: I recently asked a [similar question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4394/when-should-questions-be-moved-to-askdifferent-askubuntu). Maybe the information there is helpful to you as well.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of the one @Oliver posted. Ivo's [answer there](http://meta.superuser.com/a/4395/48078) explains it very well. **If your question is on topic here, post it here** – if you don't get an answer or feel the audience is wrong, you can request to migrate it anytime.

Comment: Post on the site you prefer. Apple.SE is not actually more specialized for Mac OS X topics than Super User.