# What is the best way to suggest that questions be migrated to other sites?

Tags: discussion, migration

For example this question, [macbook pro late 2011, mac os x lion 10.7.3, beach ball freezing](https://superuser.com/questions/392709/macbook-pro-late-2011-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-3-beach-ball-freezing), could benefit by being migrated to the [Apple - Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) What is the suggested way to do so on Superuser? Should I flag it for moderator attention. Leave a comment stating such, etc.

Comment: If you have sufficient reputation ([250](http://superuser.com/privileges/view-close-votes), you can vote to close questions. Note though, that Apple isn't listed in that list. Under that amount of reputation, you can flag it for moderator attention and if he is sure that the question absolutely has to be migrated he will do this for you. It's usually best to not leave a comment, such that the OP won't double post it or else there would be a duplicate as an unfortunate end result...

Comment: Is OP the "Original Poster"

Comment: @Tom Wijsman What do you mean by "Note though, that Apple isn't listed in that list."

Comment: OP is indeed "Original Poster". Apple isn't in the list of sites to migrate to when one would click `close` and then `off-topic` and look at the list that appears, which means that the community can't migrate a question to Apple thus only a moderator can do so. Which is what makes flagging the only option...

Comment: @MrDaniel please keep in mind that questions about OS X and Apple computers are on-topic for Super User. You [should not flag these for migration to Apple.SE](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to). Questions about non-computer Apple products (iPhone, iPad, etc.) should be marked as off-topic and sent to Apple.SE though.

Comment: I flagged your comment to the linked question as not constructive, [since you have no business telling users to migrate questions that are on topic here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4394/when-should-questions-be-moved-to-askdifferent-askubuntu/4398#4398) (likewise in the other direction — there's usually no need to migrate from Apple.SE to SU if it's on topic here). I'd also appreciate some evidence regarding your claim that the question would be better off on Apple.SE. [Also see this topic on Meta.Apple.SE](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/859/1042).

Comment: One reason is that most of the people providing feedback to the question are higher reputation users from the Apple.SE, I am not saying the question is off topic here, but there might be a better chance of getting more answers and or feedback for the question on the Apple.SE. Since the Apple.SE is only focused on Apple Hardware, etc. While SuperUser encompasses all hardware, etc. I am sure not everyone on the Apple.SE is looking here for questions to answers, etc...

Comment: Due to iOS devices, Apple?SE is not actually more specialised towards OSX questions than Super User, where iOS is off topic. How'd you like it if we pester everybody asking a command line question that would be the same on Linux to migrate it to SU, where the linux users are, even though it's perfectly on topic on Apple.SE? Just accept that you're not the one making the call, and advertising another site without proper reason is just wrong,

Comment: We had this many times before and the SU community doesn't like people doing it. It also shows no respect for a user's decision to post on a particular site. The user chooses his community. If he doesn't know about the alternatives, chances are the decision was made fr him in the way he learned about the site.

Comment: The user is this case originally chose stack exchange, sometimes the user is not making the choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you reach 3000 reputation points, you'll be able to vote to close questions. It takes 5 votes to close a question, and requires a consensus of 3/5 users for a migration to occur.  If you're under 3k, you can do the following:

1. **Flag** the question as **off topic**. If the site is not among the list of common options (e.g. [Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com)), I recommend flagging the question for **♦ moderator attention** and specifying where you think it belongs.

   [image: off topic]

   [image: attention]
2. Leave a friendly **comment** to inform the user of your choice to migrate. Users may think that they need to repost the question themselves but this is not necessary. The ♦ moderators or higher reputation users will take care of it.

   [image: comment]

Comment: What's missing of course is to make sure the question is not a good fit on *this site*. Which it is. [See also here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4394/when-should-questions-be-moved-to-askdifferent-askubuntu/4398#4398).

Comment: @nhinkle Is the `3 users to migrate` requirement for automatic migration? Or does a mod still need to be involved?

Comment: @iglvzx what do you mean? If >=3 users vote to migrate to a particular site, the migration will be done. If <3 users vote to migrate to the same site (or at all), then it will simply be closed without any migration occurring. The only time a mod needs to be involved is if the desired migration target isn't on the list.

Comment: @nhinkle There were 3 votes to migrate to the same site here: http://superuser.com/questions/396949/how-to-group-all-emails-from-one-user-into-one-collection-in-gmail?noredirect=1 Sathya had to complete the migration it seems

Comment: @iglvzx I think you may have misunderstood. I edited again to clarify. Moderators always cast binding votes, so whatever they choose is what happens, if they happen to vote to close, which is what happened in your example. If no moderator intervenes, it takes 5 votes to close a question, and if a migration is to occur, at least 3 out of the 5 must vote for the same site.