# Make [on-hold] synonymous of [closed-questions]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request, status-complete

I kindly request to make [on-hold](/questions/tagged/on-hold) synonymous with [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions)

"on-hold" was a wording used between 2013 and 2019. Nowadays, it's used "closed":

- [on-hold](/questions/tagged/on-hold) has no tag wiki and has 15 questions.
- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) has 212 questions. The tag excerpt is the following:

  > Anything about questions that were closed by community or a moderator

I found this tag while searching about Super User *community standards* related to questions about spreadsheet formulas, more specifically in the following question:

[Clear question with examples closed as unclear](https://meta.superuser.com/q/10752/1794161)

The above question has [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) and [on-hold](/questions/tagged/on-hold). It's about an Excel question.

##### Related

###### Local

- [Please don't vote to close Excel questions as off-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9099/1794161)
- [Use of [moderation] in Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14996/1794161)

###### Meta Stack Exchange

- [Every "close" has its thorn: replace "close" with "on hold" for the first five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/1359324)
- [Closing changes: [on hold], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/1359324)

###### Stack Oveflow Blog

- [New post notices: Improving feedback on Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/)
  Posted in 2019. It announces the replacement of "on hold" by "closed"

Answer (score 3):

This seems reasonable. Lets give it a week for any objections to surface and I'll take a poke at the tag synonymizing after that.

EDIT: Its done.

Comment: I agree. Thank you very much. I'm grateful for the quick response.