# Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration inadequate choices

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration has these choices:

> belongs on **meta.superuser.com** discussion, support, and feature
>   requests for this site
>
> belongs on **stackoverflow.com** Q&A for professional and enthusiast
>   programmers
>
> belongs on **serverfault.com** Q&A for professional system and network
>   administrators
>
> belongs on **webapps.stackexchange.com** Q&A for power users of web
>   applications
>
> belongs on **android.stackexchange.com** Q&A for enthusiasts and power
>   users of the Android operating system

14/48 of the 'Top Questions' list here when I posted this question were UNIX/Linux/Ubuntu related.

If there are more than five slots available, suggest adding

belongs on **https://unix.stackexchange.com/** Q&A for users and administrators of UNIX and Linux operating systems

belongs on **https://askubuntu.com/** Q&A for users and administrators of Ubuntu operating systems

I know there are many other Stack Exchange sites but those two generate a not insignificant number of questions here and if there are slots available, those communities could better serve those users IMHO, YMMV.

Comment: This is a great example why these migration paths would be harmful: Users would likely just migrate questions for no good reason ([I suggested the same thing once](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2774)). See [here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2644), [here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2726), and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) for related discussion.

Comment: There aren't more than five slots, and the stats don't justify replacing any of the current targets. Migrations from SU in the last 90 days: 5x U&L, 1x Ubuntu, 99x Webapps (6% rejected), 70x SF (7% rejected), 63x SO (3% rejected), 55x Android (9% rejected).

Comment: Also, **stop promoting Unix&Linux and Ask Ubuntu on Super User.**

Comment: Having read the other posts you suggested, I absolutely will, Commander Beck.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about a Unix-like operating system are going to overlap heavily, and provided that they fit the *general* scope of the site, they should generally just be left where they were asked.

I've got a question about getting `dpkg` or `apt-get` to tell me what changed between two versions of a package. I could conceivably go to:

- Super User, because questions about *using* an operating system are on topic here
- Unix & Linux, because Debian.
- Ask Ubuntu, if I were using Ubuntu, so let's pretend I have two systems, one running Debian, one running Ubuntu. The answer to my question would be the same for both.

What you come down to is *my* preference on where I want to ask, because my question is *equally* on topic on several sites. Remember, originally, *all* such questions were generally asked on Stack Overflow, just dressed up enough to look like a programming question to fly. The popular trick was to wrap it in the context of writing a shell script.  Super User became the *de-facto* home for questions about simply *using* a Unix-like operating system right after it launched, because you didn't have to dress your questions up any longer.

Let's say I wanted to ask my package manager question here, because I want to earn rep here to unlock privileges. I spend time coming up with a great, useful question that's perfectly on-topic here and woah, I unlock a privilege. Please, be *jealous* when it comes to the great question I just gave you, don't send it to another site just for the sake of bucketing like you would nuts and bolts.

If a question is *good* and fits within the scope of your site, *fight like hell* to keep it.